# My query that works directly to a table does not work when written to a view

Tags: oracle, view, union, oracle12c

Oracle 12c, ColdFusion 2018

I have two **identical** tables in two different databases. There is a view that uses UNION to join the data into one data set, using a database link. The view works and has no errors.

When I query the view from ColdFusion I get a "not a valid month" error.

When I query just one of the tables (and not the view), I do not get the same error.

Any idea why this would happen?

```
Table1 in database1
EmployeeID (number)
ShiftCode (varchar2)
ShiftTime (date)

Table2 in database2
EmployeeID (number)
ShiftCode (varchar2)
ShiftTime (date)


ViewBothTables  - Table1 and table2 created in database1
SELECT EmployeeID, ShiftCode, ShiftTime
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT EmployeeID, ShiftCode, ShiftTime
FROM USER.Table2@databaseConnection2


Query1 in ColdFusion - This works - returns 48 rows
SELECT employeeID, ShiftCode, ShiftTime
FROM USER.table1@databaseConnection1
Where ShiftTime <= #thisSchedWeekEnd#
            AND
      ShiftTime >= #thisSchedWeekStart# 

Query2 in ColdFusion - This works - returns 10 rows
SELECT employeeID, ShiftCode, ShiftTime
FROM USER.table2@databaseConnection2
Where ShiftTime <= #thisSchedWeekEnd#
            AND
      ShiftTime >= #thisSchedWeekStart# 

Query 3 in ColdFusion - this gives me the error
SELECT employeeID, ShiftCode, ShiftTime
FROM USER.viewBothTables@databaseConnection1
Where ShiftTime <= #thisSchedWeekEnd#
            AND
      ShiftTime >= #thisSchedWeekStart# 


[Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01843: not a valid month ORA-02063: preceding line from databaseConnection1
```

The structures are identical, Table1 and Table2 are copies of the same tables (with different people) in two separate databases. The view works, and is viewable (ha ha) I am querying from a third database. The ColdFusion date variable is identical in all three examples, because it's the same variable all three times. The first two queries work. The third says invalid month.

I have all three queries in a row on the page, exactly as above. The first two return data, the third errors out.

Yeah, the setup is stupid. I can't do much about it, they are inherited systems that I can't change and just have to deal with.

Comment: That's usually when dates are stored into VARCHAR2 column, and not all values share the same - correct - format mask.

Comment: We can't debug the code that we can't see.

Comment: I have updated my original post with the structures and more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `date format` is different between `databaseConnection1` and `databaseConnection2`.

That's why the individual query on the two different databases work and the combined query on one database doesn't work.

Can you please check the below table in both databases for `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

```
    select * from nls_session_parameters;
```

**Update 1**:-Since the date format are same for the two databases try explicit conversion of date format for the parameter like below

```
  SELECT employeeID, ShiftCode, ShiftTime
  FROM USER.viewBothTables@databaseConnection1
   Where ShiftTime <= #dateFormat(thisSchedWeekEnd, "mm/dd/yyyy")#
        AND
   ShiftTime >= #dateFormat(thisSchedWeekStart, "mm/dd/yyyy")#
```

Comment: Both are NLS_DATE_FORMAT MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: what is the value you are passing to #thisSchedWeekEnd# and #thisSchedWeekStart#

Comment: <cfset thisSchedWeekStart=#CreateDateTime(Year(theWeek1),month(theWeek1),day(theWeek1),0,0,0)#>

Comment: theWeek1 variable is a date passed the form filled out by the user. The date is validated to be a date in proper format and mm/dd/yyyy format. The identical processing is used for the WeekEnd variable.