# Not a Valid Month error from Oracle, no date in Query

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, ora-01843

I have received the most bizarre error I have encountered in a long time.

My query is:

```
select last_name
from COMPLETEDATA
```

I am querying on a view in Oracle. There are no dates in the view. The view works fine. The query above when entered into Oracle SQL Developer works fine.

When I run the page I get the following error:

> [Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01843: not a valid month

The datasource is correct, and is working in a query earlier in the page.

CF 2018
Oracle 11g

Comment: There is something you are not showing us then.  Please show the relevant table definitions and the view definition,

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your Coldfusion code? I've worked with Oracle and CF for years. I've never run into what you are describing. I'm guessing here but I don't think it's your query; I think the error is generated somewhere else in your page.

Comment: @SamM - I believe it is extremely unlikely that something outside of Oracle would know to throw a specific Oracle exception, including the Oracle error code, ORA-01843. Much more likely that there is something fishy in the view definition.

Comment: Most likely issue in my opinion: you say there is no date "in the view"; it's not clear what you mean by that. Perhaps the view columns don't include any dates; but if the view itself is defined based on dates (for example a `where` clause that filters a date or date range, or a join on dates, etc.), you might run into this. Even something as simple as a hard-coded date '01-JAN-2020' in a filter might cause this - because that is a **string**, not a date, and it is converted according to a session parameter that may have changed. DO show us the view definition (the query) first, then we'll see

Comment: Looks like you asked a similar question having this error in May https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61548835/my-query-that-works-directly-to-a-table-does-not-work-when-written-to-a-view

Comment: I forgot about that nightmare from May, I ended up not using the union and got it to work another way. I work in healthcare, and COVID doesn’t give much breathing room when people more important than I am need reports. 

I’ll post the view in the morning. I’d like to figure out the problem instead of making a work around to just “get it done”

Thanks!!

Comment: I've used CF and Oracle extensively and have never come across that error.  My gut reaction is that if this works earlier in the page then perhaps the error is being thrown by a different `cfquery` on that same page because logically it can't "work" and then "not work" just because of the location on the page.  I'd debug by process of elimination.  That is, comment out chunks of code at a time and narrow it down to the offending code.

Comment: The CF query references a view.

The view:

Comment: The CF query references a view.

The view - COMPLETEDATA -  that works in Oracle SQL developer:
    SELECT last_name
    FROM employeeList
    WHERE hireDate < '01/04/2021'

Employee List - HireDate is a Date field, there are other columns in the table that are date fields as well, but I am not referencing them in the view, so I can't see how they can impact this issue.